# EXTJS - Dynamic Package Loading Sencha Cmd 7.4

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6.5

I am trying to dynamically load a local package in my sencha app, which requires the **package-loader** package. However when I try to build my app, it fails to download **package-loader** giving an error

```
[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "package-loader"!
[ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
[ERR]       MyApp: package-loader (No matches!)
[ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements
```

I am using extjs 6.5.3 and sencha cmd 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add "package-loader" in the "requires" section of your app.json file?

If you did, you might be missing the package entirely. No worries, you can add it manually.

Details here: https://github.com/sencha/package-loader